# g++ as of 4.7 ignores the case of names inside braced #include

Tags: c++, gcc

Consider the following code where test.h attempts to include the file "signal.h" using braced include.

Signal.h:

```
#define xyz 5
int testvar;
```

test.h:

```
#if !defined (_C1)
#define _C1
#include <signal.h>
int testvar2;
#endif
```

test.cpp:

```
#include "test.h"
```

If you compile with:

```
g++ -dD -E test.cpp -o C1.i
```

All is fine and the system signal.h is pre-pended to test.cpp. However, if you compile with:

```
g++ -dD -E -I. test.cpp -o C1.i
```

The local Signal.h is pre-pended, even if it has a different case.

Is this intended behavior? This is affecting gcc-4.7, gcc-5.4 on an Ubuntu.

Thank you

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you should not define or create symbols with a leading underscore followed by an upper-case letter. [Those are reserved in all scopes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/228797/440558) for the "implementation" (compiler and standard library).

Comment: Are you building on a SMB/CIFS mount or some other form of case-insensitive filesystem?

Comment: Good point its a vboxsf...that might be the reason.

Comment: Start a shell, change to the directory where `Signal.h` is and type `cat signal.h`.

Answer (score 0):

You included the current directory as part of the search path (what #include <> looks at), that is what the -I. does. It should be fully expected to get a signal.h from the local directory first in this case. As for file name case that would dpend on your system, if the system is case-sensitive then #include should be as well, if it is not then well...

I must say that -I. is very unusual as #include "" already starts there.

Comment: I think the question is more about the case-insensitivity of the header files, `signal.h` versus `Signal.h`.

Comment: Yes that is clear - but I always thought #include is case-sensitive. It certainly is in gcc-4.6.

Comment: What do you acutally mean by "system" ? I think the term *file system* would be more accurate.